# Image of (0,1] under continous function

Tags: calculus

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Which of the following sets cannot be image of $(0,1]$ under $f$.

1. {$0$}
2. $(0,1)$
3. $[0,1)$
4. $[0,1]$

My initial guess was using intermediate value theorem, but it seems hopeless here. What concept could one use here to solve this question?

Comment: I bet you can think of concrete examples yielding three of them.

Comment: For 1 fxn can be zero fxn, for 3 fxn can be taken x-1 but what fxn to take for option 4?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Consider two sequences $(x_n),(y_n)\subseteq(0,1]$ so that $f(x_n)\to 0$ and $f(y_n)\to 1$. You can get convergent subsequences for each of them, and use continuity to figure out where the value at the function of the limit point ends up.

Alternatively, just consider $f([0,1])$, which must be a closed interval by intermediate value theorem.* Now what can $f((0,1])$ be?

*-The theorem you will learn for metric spaces would be "compactness is preserved by a continuous transformation".

Answer (score 0):

I also suggest to use concrete examples. You have to be careful because you can't directly argue that by pre-image of open(closed) set under continuous function is open (closed), because in general $A\subset f^{-1}(f(A))$.

for 1, $y=0$,

for 3, $y=1-x$,

for 4, $y=4(x-\frac{1}{2})^2$,

so it gives you 2 be the answer.

For a direct proof, use compactness is preserved under continuous functions. If $f(0,1]=(0,1)$, and $(0,1)\subset f[0,1]$ which is compact (hence closed), then we have $[0,1]\subset f[0,1]$, which means $f(0)$ should correspond to 2 values at least, ie. $0$ and $1$, which is impossible.

Comment: it does not imply the answer is (ii). it means the answer is not among the choices. you did not, as i assumed that there is an answer here, give a reason for (ii).

Comment: @abel See my answer for a reason without needing those theorems that you have not learnt yet.

Comment: @abel The argument I thought need some knowledge about topology, in particular closed set and compactness. I am not sure whether you have learnt them.